# how to skip a line in a while

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I'm trying to convert php into pdf with the function FPDF but I did  a select on my data base and I would like to have all the element of this select in PDF:

```
$query="select organisme,id from client";
$resultats=$db->query($query);
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFillColor(232,232,232);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(20,6,'ID',1,0,'C',100);
$pdf->Cell(70,6,'mes organismes',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);

while ($row = $resultats->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $pdf->Cell(20,6,utf8_decode($row['id']),1,0,'C',1); 
  $pdf->Cell(70,6,$row['organisme'],1,0,'C',1);
}

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

But the problem is that I got the ID and organisme but I have a problem :

[image]

i would like to know how I do to skip line into all new id and organisme

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

FPDF's `Ln()` function performs a line break.

```
$pdf->Ln();
```

Add this line below your `$pdf->Cell()` function calls, both for the header row and inside the `while` loop.